# React Router persist transition info during modal login/registration

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've found a bunch of React Router 'auth' examples, all of which use replaceState to go to a login route and then a canned location after login. What I am looking for is an example where login and registration are modal (not directly tied to their own routes) that are state based and can triggered from anywhere with the app at any point.

What I'd like to do is if the user invokes an action via the GUI or goes directly to a URL/route that 'requires auth' and is not logged in, show the modals and then AFTER login and/or register/login send then to the route they were trying to get to. Otherwise send them to the route they came from or the home page if not prior route (i.e. they entered a URL in the browser directly).

The things I've been able to find assume that login is it's own route and then redirect to some canned location (not where the user was trying to go in the first place). Keep in mind a user may toggle between registration and login modals any number of times so I need to persist where they wanted to go until they cancel, or succeed. If cancel, is easy but on success where and how can I persist and then transition to the requested route?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this works...

```
export default {
  path: '/',
  component: App,
  indexRoute: { component: Child },
  childRoutes: [ //<- ***REGULAR ROUTES ARE CHILDREN HERE***
    { path: 'test1', component: Child1 },
    { path: 'test2', component: Child2 },
    { component: AuthHandler,  
      childRoutes: [  //<- ***AUTH ROUTES ARE CHILDREN HERE***
        {path: 'test3', component: Child3},
        {path: 'test4', component: Child4}
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

...Going to /test1 or /test2 are unsecured routes (as would any of tests' direct children be as well as / itself). However, any children under the AuthHandler child (which does not have or need a path unless you really want one) will first go through the AuthHandler - where you can do whatever you want. So /test3 and /test4 are secure routes (assuming you handle auth in the AuthHandler in your preferred way). This will also work with JSX syntax routes provided they are nested the same.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways I could think of:

1. All your `<Route/>` specific `pageCompoenent`s extend an `AuthComponent` which by default handles the display of login or registration modals.
2. All the `<Route/>` specific `pageCompoenent` are children of a parent `<Route/>` component `AuthHandler` which renders all child routes via `{this.props.children}`.

I personally prefer the second solution. Example Code:

```jsx
    // Soln2
    // Route Declaration
    <Route name='auth' path='/' component={AuthHandler}>
      <Route name='settings' path='/settings' component={SettingsPage} />
      <Route name='about' path='/about' component={AboutPage} />
      <Route name='someother' path='/someother' component={SomeOtherPage} />
    </Route>

    // AuthHandler
    class AuthHandler extends React.Component{
      componentWillMount(){
        if(!Authenticated) showLoginRegisterModal();
      }
      componentWillReceiveProps(){
        if(!Authenticated) showLoginRegisterModal();
      }
      showLoginRegisterModal(){
        // Handle how you wish to show your modal, by style/class/this.state.ifShow
      }
      render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <ModalComponent ifShow={this.state.ifShow}/>
            <div {...this.props}>
              {this.props.children} // Your child pages will get rendered here
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    class ModalComponent extends React.Component{
      // Some member functions
      render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <LoginComponent ifShow={this.state.ifLoginShow}/>
            <RegisterComponent ifShow={this.state.ifRegisterShow}/>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: Does this mean the auth routes MUST have an extra path segment?

Comment: In the above example, all other routes are child routes of this auth route. You can add another component which does not require auth for path='/' above <AuthHandler/>. This way your login will only be dependent on modals (If your concern is what will happen if I navigate to path="/")

Comment: Well... in my case '/' and some of it's children do NOT require auth, but others do. So per the proposed solution, would I need a child path segment of 'auth' or something as the parent under '/' for the secure routes? If I have 2 '/' one with auth and one without what would happen going to '/'? Never seen a router where something like this was so complex...

Comment: Well it is complex. Will post another answer tonight.